# How can I dynamically change parameter of source block?

Tags: simulink

I need to put a source block (i.e. ramp) in a for loop iterator in Simulink, and then change its parameter depending on i-th iteration. 
For example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov32E.png

I want to change (in this specific case) the value of amax, that's a vector with N elements. At every loop, I need to iterate over this vector.
How can I do this?

- UPDATE

This is the model:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdXzQ.png

In the red windows there are the trapezoidal waveform generator, generated at different time to have something like this:

VIEW COMMENTS

Here I use value of slope and time taken by a vector like in the first image. I want to create more than two waveforms using only one waveform generator with the help of a "for iterator" or something else.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a trapezoidal velocity profile made by a sum of four ramp. I need to link more than 2 trapezoidal wave without more ramps but using only a set of one wave iterating the values on it and adding the previous wave on the actual. How can I do it?

Comment: How would that look like? Can you show your model? I don't get the idea.

Comment: I've updated the answer. This is the second link http://i.stack.imgur.com/HO7WM.png

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have one source that generates your base signal... then at the end you want a vector of signals that are a modifed version of the base signal. For that purpose i recommend using a for each subsystem... one input is the base signal, and the second input is the vector of parameters that are aplied on the modification function in the [for each subsystem](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/foreachsubsystem.html)... the output will be a vector again.